# что такое backend - ы

Tags: php, backend

Сегодня был на собеседование на позицию Junior PHP. Мне задали одну устную задачу.
Цитирую "Представь что у тебя есть 100 бэкендов, в одном из бэкендов были изменения в кэше, как я разошлю эти изменения другим бэкендам? через какой протокол? я ответил что через TCP, на что получил ответ, что он не надежен для таких целей".
Так вот, что такое Бэкенд? и через какой протокол им лучше общаться?

Comment: Полагаю интервьювер имел в виду экземпляр сервера. Вопрос очень странный и я думаю что он ожидал от Вас что Вы будете задавать дополнительные вопросы. Например: у этих бэкэндов одна бд или нет. они физически рядом или нет. итд.

Comment: Junior PHP и не знает что такое бэкэнд.....вы че, серьезно?

Если это БД - то должна быть настроена репликация.

Если это 100 идентичных серверов, которые объединены в один большой...эм...кластер., то можно чем угодно. Хоть запускать вручную Rsync, прости господи. 
Вопрос вам задали слишком общий.

Comment: Экзаменатор - даун.